# choose warning when no radio button button is selected

Tags: django

I have created a short questionnaire with radio buttons using django. When no option is selected I get a warning saying "Please select one of these options" which is good. What I don't like is the fact that an arrow points at the first radio button and also creates a square around it.There is a chance that a person completing the questionnaire might get confused and choose the first option because of the warning. My question is, is it possible to alter the warning box? Maybe shift it to the right and remove the arrow so it seems like it's a warning corresponding to the whole set of radio buttons and not just the first one.

My models.py is(goes up to choice 17 but each is the same as choice1):

```
class Value(models.Model):
  SN=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, verbose_name='StudentNumber')
  choice1=models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, verbose_name="V1")
  user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My forms.py is:

```
options=[
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '2'),
  ('3', '3'),
  ('4', '4'),
  ('5', '5')
  ]
class ValueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SN=forms.CharField(label='Please input your Student 
No',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Student No'}))
choice1=choice2=choice3=choice4=choice5=choice6=choice7=choice8=choice9=choice10=choice11=choice12=choice13=choice14=choice15=choice16=choice17=forms.ChoiceField( choices=options, widget=RadioSelect(),)
class Meta:
    model=Value
    fields=["SN","choice1","choice2","choice3","choice4","choice5","choice6","choice7","choice8","choice9","choice10","choice11","choice12","choice13","choice14","choice15","choice16","choice17",]
```

My views.py is (have only added the first question from Questions):

```
def question_values(request):
    form = ValueForm()
    Questions = {'Q1':'1. Study effectively on your own in independent private study'}
    return render(request,'questionnaire/index.html', {'form':form, 'Questions':Questions})

def create_survey(request):
    form=ValueForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        answers=form.save(commit=False)
        answers.user=request.user
        answers.save()
        return redirect('/result')
    values=Value.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    datas=[values.SN,values.choice1,values.choice2,values.choice3,values.choice4,
         values.choice5,values.choice6,values.choice7,values.choice8,values.choice9,
         values.choice10,values.choice11,values.choice12,values.choice13,values.choice14,
         values.choice15,values.choice16,values.choice17 
      ]       
    return render(request, 'questionnaire/result.html', {'form':form, 'values':values, 'datas':datas})
```

I got the values and datas so I could try {{values.choice1}} to print a specific value and {{datas}} to print all values on the result template = so I could check whether the code works.

and for index.html I couldn't manage to make a loop so I did it individually for each question:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">      
    <label>{{Questions.Q1}}</label>
  </div>      
  <div class="col-md-4">
  {% for radio in form.choice1 %}
    <label class="radio-inline">{{radio}}</label>
  {% endfor %}  
</div> 
</div>
```

where Questions is a dictionairy I created in views

I have searched quite a bit but couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPhu.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we have a look of it?

Comment: Yes sorry, I added a link with a screenshot

Comment: what you want belongs to the browser, this may be different across different browsers. What you can do is set `required=False` to the field, clean the data yourself in forms and design your own warning box

Comment: the thing is I don't want to have any empty answers. If I set `required=False` if someone misses a question I won't get a value. Or will my own warning box still stop them from submitting? If so I have no idea how to create one. What I was trying all along was to alter the default box one or hide it and create my own but couldn't find any code that was relevant. Also, I tried the code in Safari on a Mac and got the same form.

Comment: actually I think I get what you're suggesting. Create a box with my own text and using an if  statement display it if there is no value returned? If that's it, I'm not sure exactly how to connect the if statement with the html display but I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Check my answer, I explained how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

What you want belongs to the browser, this may be different across different browsers. What you can do is:

- set `required=False` to the field

  ```
  class ValueForm(forms.ModelForm):
       choice1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=options,required=False,
                     widget=RadioSelect())
  ```
- clean the data yourself in forms

  ```
   class ValueForm(forms.ModelForm):
       choice1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=options,required=False,
                     widget=RadioSelect())

        def clean_choice1(self):
            data = self.cleaned_data.get('choice1')
            if not data:
                self.add_error("choice1","Please select one of these options")
  ```
- Design your own warning box, (The one of bootstrap is perfect)

  ```
    {% if form.choice1.errors %}
          <span class="custom-warning-box"> 
          {{form.choice1.errors.as_text}}
          </span>
    {% endif %}
    {% for radio in form.choice1 %}
         <label class="radio-inline">{{radio}}</label>
    {% endfor %}
  ```

Comment: The answer makes sense so I'm not sure what's wrong. I only did it for choice one but when I click submit it gets completely ignored as if there's required=False and no other code and it just says Please select one of these choices for the second question. It seems like the error hasn't been added in the forms section although I don't understand why that is.

Comment: I have a text box and 17 questions. I also tried applying the code to all questions and when I hit submit I just went on to the next page even though no choices were selected.

Comment: in your form validations, add `print(choice1)` to see the value of it. if you can, let me see your form validations

Comment: My code just suddenly stopped working even though I haven't changed anything. What I used to have was:                        `form=ValueForm(request.POST) if form.is_valid():
            answers=form.save(commit=False)
            answers.user=request.user
            answers.save()
            return redirect('/result')`.       And I then had `values=Value.objects.order_by('-id')[0]` and printed that on the template by using `{{values.choice1}}` but now I'm getting "Cannot assign SimpleLazyObject" error for the `answers.user=request.user` line.

Comment: for some reason which I don't understand, after I logged on to the admin page it finally started working again. With the `{{values.}}` I get the previous saved values when I leave them blank and the weird thing is I get "NOT NULL constraint failed" if I choose a radio option

Comment: please add the new edit of your code in your post that's how I can help you

Comment: I updated my code and even though before the clean_choice did nothing I now keep getting "NOT NULL constraint failed" and had to comment that part of the code out.